# Duplication Elimination With Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble understanding this problem. It asks, to read in 20 values from the user, validate that they are between 10 and 100. If the data is valid, store it in an array only if it is not a duplicate. After going through the 20 values, only display the unique values. I don't know why but in my code it is storing every value regardless if it is a duplicate or not. I appreciate any help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int duplicate[20];
    int numberEntered;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    bool dup = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) duplicate[i] = 0; //initializes all indices to 0


    cout << "Enter 20 numbers " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Number " << endl;
        cin >> numberEntered;

        if((numberEntered > 10) && (numberEntered < 100) )
        {
           for (int j = 0; j < currentIndex; j++)
           {

               if(duplicate[i] == numberEntered)
               {
                   cout << "This number was already entered " << endl;
                   dup = true;
                   break;
               }

           }

            if(dup==false)
            {
                duplicate[currentIndex] = numberEntered;
                currentIndex++;
            }      
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Number, must be between 10 and 100 " << endl;
            i -- ;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
    {
        cout  << duplicate[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use algorithms like `std::find_if`. Code can be a bit much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
    if(duplicate[i] == numberEntered)
    {
        cout << "This number was already entered " << endl;
        dup = true;
        break;
    }
```

you're checking against `duplicate[i]`, not against index `j` which is the loop checking for duplicates, so your code will never see a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that. But now whenever you put in a duplicate, it doesn't store any subsequent numbers. For example, when I put in 12, it stores 12. 13, stores 13. 14 stores 14. Now, enter 12 again, it doesn't store it. Now, try to enter 56, doesn't store it. It just stops...

Comment: That's because you don't reset `dup` to false. Why don't you just go through the code step by step with a debugger. That will point you to these logical errors naturally.

Comment: How would you do that? Code in debugging statements? Or can you use the actual debugger because I never use that I don't really know how it works